# Как реализовать поиск количества повторения фразы в документе?

Tags: c#, текст

Фраза состоит из слов и разделителей. Проверку наличия искомой фразы я сделал, но далее появилась трудность. Дело в том, что порядок слов во входной строке может быть любым. Понимаю, что можно перебрать текст через цикл и, просто "собирая" эти самые фразы, выяснить их количество, но интересует более оптимальный способ если таковой существует (сам лично пробовал через regex, но ничего путного не вышло).

Пример: фраза "aa" в тексте "aa aa bb" должна найтись два раза, фраза "aa bb" в тексте "aa bbc" найтись не должна, в тексте "aa bb bb" должна найтись один раз.

UPD: поиск вроде как сделал, но он не работает на фразах с повторяющимися словами.

```
private static int GetPhraseCount(string input, string phrase)
{
    var count = 0;
    var phraseByWords = Regex.Matches(phrase, @"\w+");
    var timesWordsFound = new List<int>();
    
    foreach (var item in phraseByWords)
    {
        var word = item.ToString();
        
        timesWordsFound.Add(Regex.Matches(input, @"\b" + word + @"\b").Count);
    }
    
    count = timesWordsFound.Min();
        
    return count;
}
```

UPD 2: переписал предыдущую функцию, но она неоптимальна по сложности

```
public static int GetPhraseCount(string input, string phrase)
{
    var count = 0;
    
    var inputInWords = Regex.Matches(input, @"\b\w+\b");
    var phraseInWords = Regex.Matches(phrase, @"\b\w+\b");
    
    var wordsCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    
    foreach (var item in phraseInWords)
        wordsCount[item.ToString()] = 0;
    
    foreach (var item in inputInWords)
    {
        var word = item.ToString();
        
        if (wordsCount.ContainsKey(word))
            wordsCount[word]++;
    }
    
    var exit = false;
    
    while (!exit) 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < phraseInWords.Count; i++)
        {
            var word = phraseInWords[i].ToString();
            
            if (wordsCount[word] != 0)
                wordsCount[word]--;
            else 
            {
                exit = true;
                break;
            }

            if (i == phraseInWords.Count - 1)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Стоит добавить в вопрос примеров. Без них - непонятно.

Comment: "порядок слов во входной строке может быть любым" - в примере непонятно как это влияет. Можете привести еще пример по этому требованию?

Comment: Ну, грубо говоря, если бы была дана точная фраза - можно было бы обойтись Regex.Matches(text, phrase). А в данной ситуации порядок, как я уже упоминал, может быть разный. И если дана фраза "find me", в тексте "me something something find" она по условию задачи присутствует.

Comment: А "me something something find" и "me something. something find" обе считаются или нет?

Comment: Если Вы имеете ввиду точку, то да, это никак не влияет. Эквивалентны, если опираться на условие.

Comment: Тогда ваша задача по сути к проверке наличия в документе всех слов из вашей фразы. Не важно как они расположены. Количество определяется количеством повторов самого редкого слова.

Comment: Разбейте строку на слова, посчитайте при этом количество повторений для каждого слова, создав уникальный словарь, например `Dictionary<string, int>`, где ключ - слово, а значение - количество повторений. Это называется индексация. Далее, смотрите уже по созданному индексу для каждого слова нужные данные. Регулярки здесь возможно пригодятся только для разбивки предложения на слова.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но уже разобрался. Судя по всему, сделал аналогичное Вашим предложениям.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int GetPhraseCount(string input, string phrase)
{
var count = 0;

var inputInWords = Regex.Matches(input, @"\b\w+\b");
var phraseInWords = Regex.Matches(phrase, @"\b\w+\b");

var wordsCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var item in phraseInWords)
    wordsCount[item.ToString()] = 0;

foreach (var item in inputInWords)
{
    var word = item.ToString();
    
    if (wordsCount.ContainsKey(word))
        wordsCount[word]++;
}

var exit = false;

while (!exit) 
{
    for (var i = 0; i < phraseInWords.Count; i++)
    {
        var word = phraseInWords[i].ToString();
        
        if (wordsCount[word] != 0)
            wordsCount[word]--;
        else 
        {
            exit = true;
            break;
        }

        if (i == phraseInWords.Count - 1)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}

return count;
}
```